# how to test axios interceptors with jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, axios

In my project, I have a namespace that exports some functions that use Axios, in the same file I add an interceptor to axios instance like that :

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (res) => res,
    (error) => {
      if (
        error.response &&
        (error.response.status?.toString() === "400" ||
          error.response.status?.toString() === "403" ||
          error.response.status?.toString() === "404")
      ) {
        return Promise.reject(
          Error(JSON.stringify(error.response.data?.status?.errors[0]))
        );
      } else if (error.response) {
        return Promise.reject(
          Error(
            `server responsed with the following code: ${error.response?.status} and the following message: ${error.response?.statusText}`
          )
        );
      } else if (error.request) {
        return Promise.reject(
          Error(
            "The request was made but no response was received, check your network connection"
          )
        );
      } else Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

I want to test that this interceptor works as expected, I search the forms here and googled a lot but all the answers are basically mocking the interceptor not testing it.

I have tried:

1. mocking the response of an axios post request and checking the AxiosPromise that gets returned but it only contained the result I mocked. it seems that it ignores the interceptor when I mock using `mockResolvedValue`.
2. I have tried adding an interceptor to the mocked axios instance but that did not work too.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

What about pulling the function out and testing it without axios?

```
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosResponse } from 'axios'

export const onFulfilled = (response: AxiosResponse) => {
  // Your interceptor handling a successful response
}
export const onRejected = (error: AxiosError) => {
  // Your interceptor handling a failed response
}

axios.interceptors.response.use(onFulfilled, onRejected)
```

Now you can test the functions onFullfilled and onRejected with less dependencies to axios.

Comment: This way the test misses a part because it's not evident that these interceptors are in effect.

Comment: this still misses the point as @EstusFlask explains above. but thanks

Comment: maybe i can try this workaround and test if they are being called. but am not really sure if that's correct. i will give it a try and lyk. @simon flepp

Comment: @EstusFlask: There is no need to test that the interceptors are in effect because that's Axios' responsibility. Doing so would be testing that Axios works correctly, which is completely unnecessary. This should be the correct answer.

Comment: @SashaChedygov It's questionable if interceptor function can be considered a separate unit that can be tested in isolation. Even then, this test would totally rely on dev's understanding of the internal work of axios interceptors which can be wrong and so make a test useless. It makes sense to not test a framework and rely on it's documented behaviour, but for random third-party libs integration tests can be more practical, at least if they are test-friendly (axios is). But to make it clear, I specifically referred to that `response.use()` call is not tested, the answer doesn't explain that

Answer (score 3):

You have to mock the interceptor and run the callbacks.

Here is an example on how to do it:

httpService.ts

```
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.baseURL = process.env.API_URL || "http://localhost:5000";
  return config;
});

axios.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
  const expectedError =
    error.response &&
    error.response.status >= 400 &&
    error.response.status < 500;

  if (!expectedError) {
    toast.error("An unexpected error occured");
  }

  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default {
  get: axios.get,
  post: axios.post,
  put: axios.put,
  delete: axios.delete,
};
```

httpService.test.ts

```
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "./httpService";

jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: {
    interceptors: {
      request: { use: jest.fn(() => {}) },
      response: { use: jest.fn(() => {}) },
    },
  },
}));

const fakeError = {
  response: {
    status: undefined,
  },
};

const mockRequestCallback = (axios.interceptors.request.use as jest.Mock).mock
  .calls[0][0];
const mockResponseErrorCallback = (axios.interceptors.response.use as jest.Mock)
  .mock.calls[0][1];
const toastErrorSpy = jest.spyOn(toast, "error");

beforeEach(() => {
  toastErrorSpy.mockClear();
});

test("request error interceptor", () => {
  expect(mockRequestCallback({})).toStrictEqual({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
  });
});

test("unexpected error on response interceptor", () => {
  fakeError.response.status = 500;

  mockResponseErrorCallback(fakeError).catch(() => {});
  expect(toastErrorSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

test("expected error on response interceptor", () => {
  fakeError.response.status = 400;

  mockResponseErrorCallback(fakeError).catch(() => {});
  expect(toastErrorSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: I don’t see how this is testing the interceptor. It’s merely testing whether the interceptor would be called. The interceptor’s implementation could be completely changed and the test wouldn’t be able to see whether the code is still working. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're wasting a lot of code and effort to merely test that `use` gets called, which doesn't actually buy you anything. In practice, this is no different than [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65980504/104184) but much more brittle and verbose. You're better off just testing the interceptors directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with you and this is how I solved it:

```
  const axiosResponse = await axios.get(your-url);

  expect(axiosResponse.config.headers.Authorization).toBe('Bearer test-token');
```

From the axiosResponse you can test all of logic you set in the interceptors

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Use this mock functionality

```
jest.mock('axios', () => {
   return {
      interceptors: {
         request: {
            use: jest.fn(),
            eject: jest.fn()
         },
         response: {
            use: jest.fn(),
            eject: jest.fn()
         },
      },
   };
});
```

Comment: And how could I test that later?
could you share a full example?