# How to test request value returned in a middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm new to react and I have something like this to test.

```
function getProfit() {
  let profit = 0;

  ** some axios called where profit is updated form the returned value **

  return (req, res, next) => {
    req.properties = {
      profit,
    };

    next();
  };
}

module.exports = {
  getProfit,
};
```

I want to test the returned value of this function. I tried something like this but it's not working:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const axios = require('axios');
const properties = require('../../middleware/properties');

describe('Properties Middleware', () => {
  let sandbox;
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should return the profit value in request', async () => {
    const profitMockData = { profit: 100 };

    sandbox.stub(axios, 'get').resolves({ data: 100 });

    const req = jest.fn()
    const res = { sendStatus: jest.fn() }
    const next = jest.fn();

    const response = await properties.getProfit(req, res, next);

    expect(response.req.properties.profit).toEqual(profitMockData.profit);

  });
});
```

This part `response.req.properties.profit` is wrong as I don't know how to get the value from req.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe I am understanding your question wrong, but I feel like the answer you're looking for is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980172/how-to-test-axios-interceptors-with-jest

Comment: Hi @EtienneMartel, Thanks for your comment. I had a look but mine is much simplier. I can see the test works when I debug and evaluate the `response` variable. It's just that I don't know how to retrieve the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const axios = require('axios');
const properties = require('../../middleware/properties');

describe('Properties Middleware', () => {
  let sandbox;
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should return the profit value in request', async () => {
    const profitMockData = { profit: 100 };

    sandbox.stub(axios, 'get').resolves({ data: 100 });

    const response = await properties.getProfit(req, res, next);

    const req = {};
    response(req, {}, () => {});

    expect(response.req.properties.profit).toEqual(profitMockData.profit);

  });
});
```

I've finally figured it out with help of a coworker. So, first, you to all the functions after stubbing the get part and then assign it to req, {}, () => {}. We don't need the res and next as we only care about the req here that's why we didn't have them as variables as well.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.